# How to use Except function with spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to get differences between two dataframe but returning the row with the different fields only. For example, I have 2 dataframes as follow:

```
val DF1 = Seq(
    (3,"Chennai",  "rahman",9846, 45000,"SanRamon"),
    (1,"Hyderabad","ram",9847, 50000,"SF")
).toDF("emp_id","emp_city","emp_name","emp_phone","emp_sal","emp_site")

val DF2 = Seq(
    (3,"Chennai",  "rahman",9846, 45000,"SanRamon"),
    (1,"Sydney","ram",9847, 48000,"SF")
).toDF("emp_id","emp_city","emp_name","emp_phone","emp_sal","emp_site")
```

The only difference between these two dataframe is `emp_city` and `emp_sal` for the second row.
Now, I am using the `except` function which gives me the entire row as follow:

```
DF1.except(DF2)

+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name|emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
|     1|Hyderabad|     ram|     9847|  50000|      SF|
+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
```

However, I need the output to be like this:

```
+---------+--------+-----+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_sal|
+------+---------+-------+
|     1|Hyderabad|  50000| 
+------+---------+-------+
```

Which shows the different cells as well as `emp_id`.

**Edit :**
if there is change in column then it should appear if there is no change then it should be hidden or Null

Comment: How would the expected output look if the `emp_id=3` rows differ in, for example, the `emp_name` column?

Comment: Also, different rows can differ in different columns. emp_name or emp_phone. How should the final result look like in that case ?

Comment: problem statement is not much clear

Comment: if there is change in column then it should appear if there is no change then it should be hidden

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338412/how-to-compare-two-dataframe-and-print-columns-that-are-different-in-scala the solution is explained in this thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338412/how-to-compare-two-dataframe-and-print-columns-that-are-different-in-scala The solution is explained in this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution which seems to be working fine :

```
val cols = DF1.columns.filter(_ != "emp_id").toList
val DF3 = DF1.except(DF2)
def mapDiffs(name: String) = when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name", null ).otherwise(array($"l.$name", $"r.$name")).as(name)
val result = DF2.as("l").join(DF3.as("r"), "emp_id").select($"emp_id" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)
```

It generates the output as follow :

```
+------+-------------------+--------+---------+--------------+--------+
|emp_id|           emp_city|emp_name|emp_phone|       emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+-------------------+--------+---------+--------------+--------+
|     1|[Sydney, Hyderabad]|    null|     null|[48000, 50000]|    null|
|    
+------+-------------------+--------+---------+--------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4):

The following should give you the result you are looking for.

DF1.except(DF2).select("emp_id","emp_city","emp_sal")

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the comment from @user238607 as we cannot predict which columns are going to differ,

Still you can try this workaround.

I'm assuming `emp_id` is unique,

```
scala> val diff = udf((col: String, c1: String, c2: String) => if (c1 == c2) "" else col )

scala> DF1.join(DF2, DF1("emp_id") === DF2("emp_id"))
res15: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emp_id: int, emp_city: string ... 10 more fields]

scala> res15.withColumn("diffcolumn", split(concat_ws(",",DF1.columns.map(x => diff(lit(x), DF1(x), DF2(x))):_*),","))
res16: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emp_id: int, emp_city: string ... 11 more fields]

scala> res16.show(false)
+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------------+
|emp_id|emp_city |emp_name|emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|emp_id|emp_city|emp_name|emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|diffcolumn                 |
+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------------+
|3     |Chennai  |rahman  |9846     |45000  |SanRamon|3     |Chennai |rahman  |9846     |45000  |SanRamon|[, , , , , ]               |
|1     |Hyderabad|ram     |9847     |50000  |SF      |1     |Sydney  |ram     |9847     |48000  |SF      |[, emp_city, , , emp_sal, ]|
+------+---------+--------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------------+

scala> val diff_cols = res16.select(explode($"diffcolumn")).filter("col != ''").distinct.collect.map(a=>col(a(0).toString))

scala> val exceptOpr = DF1.except(DF2)

scala> exceptOpr.select(diff_cols:_*).show

+-------+---------+
|emp_sal| emp_city|
+-------+---------+
|  50000|Hyderabad|
+-------+---------+
```