# Comparing data between two spark dataframes and populating PASS if match and FAIL at corresponding colums

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am having two spark data frames like below

[Source1 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gLfi.png)

[Source2 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPx51.png)

I am using pyspark python to compare the data between the two sources using the Snapshot_Date as Key column and want to display the result in another dataframe like below

[Compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/firOf.png)
color coding is for easy understanding and not needed

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are the columns to be compared numeric always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [spark-extension](https://github.com/g-research/spark-extension) package mentioned in this answer [Compare two dataframes Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279160/compare-two-dataframes-pyspark)

You can modify the `result` dataframe to get the final dataframe appropriately.

```
from gresearch.spark.diff import *

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
        ("Source1",20201116, 436039, 123, 222, 333,0, 555),
        ("Source1",20201117,436034, 234, 34, 7, 5, 678)
      ]

df1Columns = ["Source","Snapshot_Date","REC_COUNT","Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

print("Source1 dataframe")
df1.show(truncate=False)

data2 = [
        ("Source2", 20201116,436039,234,234,333,0,555),
        ("Source2", 20201117,436034,234,5,7,5,678)
      ]

df2Columns = ["Source", "Snapshot_Date","REC_COUNT","Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5"]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema = df2Columns)

print(" Source2 dataframe")
df2.show(truncate=False)

options = DiffOptions().with_change_column("changes")
result = df1.diff_with_options(df2, options, 'Snapshot_Date')

result.select("Snapshot_Date", "diff","changes").show(truncate=False)
```

The output is as shown. The column `changes` lists down the columns in which changes are present.

```
Source1 dataframe
+-------+-------------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+
|Source |Snapshot_Date|REC_COUNT|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|
+-------+-------------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+
|Source1|20201116     |436039   |123 |222 |333 |0   |555 |
|Source1|20201117     |436034   |234 |34  |7   |5   |678 |
+-------+-------------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+

 Source2 dataframe
+-------+-------------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+
|Source |Snapshot_Date|REC_COUNT|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|
+-------+-------------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+
|Source2|20201116     |436039   |234 |234 |333 |0   |555 |
|Source2|20201117     |436034   |234 |5   |7   |5   |678 |
+-------+-------------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+

+-------------+----+--------------------+
|Snapshot_Date|diff|changes             |
+-------------+----+--------------------+
|20201116     |C   |[Source, Col1, Col2]|
|20201117     |C   |[Source, Col2]      |
+-------------+----+--------------------+
```