# Why am I getting column ambigioutiy error in my pyspark query?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a column that identifies which columns are updated as part of a change data feed (I followed this stackoverflow: [Compare two dataframes Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279160/compare-two-dataframes-pyspark)), but when I reference my own tables, I get this error:

```
AnalysisException:Column _commit_version#203599L, subscribe_status#203595, _change_type#203598, _commit_timestamp#203600, subscribe_dt#203596, end_sub_dt#203597 are ambiguous.
```

It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same. This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one. Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g:

`df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id")`.

You can also set `spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin` to false to disable this check.

This is my code:

````
df_X = df1.filter(df1['_change_type'] == 'update_preimage')
df_Y = df1.filter(df1['_change_type'] == 'update_postimage')


dfX.show()
dfY.show()
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, lit, when, array_remove

# get conditions for all columns except id
# conditions_ = [when(dfX[c]!=dfY[c], lit(c)).otherwise("") for c in dfX.columns if c != ['external_id', '_change_type']]

select_expr =[
                col("external_id"), 
                *[dfY[c] for c in dfY.columns if c != 'external_id'], 
                # array_remove(array(*conditions_), "").alias("column_names")
]

print(select_expr)

dfX.join(dfY, "external_id").select(*select_expr).show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I aliased my initial variables and it worked:

```
dfY = df1.filter(df1['_change_type'] == 'update_postimage').alias('y')


dfX.show()
dfY.show()
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, lit, when, array_remove

# get conditions for all columns except id
conditions_ = [
    when(col("x." + c) != col("y." + c), lit(c)).otherwise("").alias("condition_" + c)
    for c in dfX.columns if c not in ['external_id', '_change_type']
]

select_expr =[
                col("external_id"), 
                *[col("y." + c).alias("y_" + c) for c in dfY.columns if c != 'external_id'],
                array_remove(array(*conditions_), "").alias("column_names")
]

display(dfX.join(dfY, "external_id").select(*select_expr))
```