# How to compare two identically structured dataframes to calculate the row differences

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I've the following two identically structurred dataframes with id in common.

```
val originalDF = Seq((1,"gaurav","jaipur",550,70000),(2,"sunil","noida",600,80000),(3,"rishi","ahmedabad",510,65000))
                .toDF("id","name","city","credit_score","credit_limit")
scala> originalDF.show(false)
+---+------+---------+------------+------------+
|id |name  |city     |credit_score|credit_limit|
+---+------+---------+------------+------------+
|1  |gaurav|jaipur   |550         |70000       |
|2  |sunil |noida    |600         |80000       |
|3  |rishi |ahmedabad|510         |65000       |
+---+------+---------+------------+------------+
val changedDF= Seq((1,"gaurav","jaipur",550,70000),(2,"sunil","noida",650,90000),(4,"Joshua","cochin",612,85000))
                .toDF("id","name","city","credit_score","credit_limit")
scala> changedDF.show(false)
+---+------+------+------------+------------+
|id |name  |city  |credit_score|credit_limit|
+---+------+------+------------+------------+
|1  |gaurav|jaipur|550         |70000       |
|2  |sunil |noida |650         |90000       |
|4  |Joshua|cochin|612         |85000       |
+---+------+------+------------+------------+
```

Hence I wrote one udf to calulate the change in column values.

```
val diff = udf((col: String, c1: String, c2: String) => if (c1 == c2) "" else col )
val somedf=changedDF.alias("a").join(originalDF.alias("b"), col("a.id") === col("b.id")).withColumn("diffcolumn", split(concat_ws(",",changedDF.columns.map(x => diff(lit(x), changedDF(x), originalDF(x))):_*),","))
scala> somedf.show(false)
+---+------+------+------------+------------+---+------+------+------------+------------+----------------------------------+
|id |name  |city  |credit_score|credit_limit|id |name  |city  |credit_score|credit_limit|diffcolumn                        |
+---+------+------+------------+------------+---+------+------+------------+------------+----------------------------------+
|1  |gaurav|jaipur|550         |70000       |1  |gaurav|jaipur|550         |70000       |[, , , , ]                        |
|2  |sunil |noida |650         |90000       |2  |sunil |noida |600         |80000       |[, , , credit_score, credit_limit]|
+---+------+------+------------+------------+---+------+------+------------+------------+----------------------------------+
```

But I'm not able to get id and diffcolumn separately. If I do a
somedf.select('id) it gives me ambiguity error coz there are two ids in the joined table
I want to get all the name of the columns in any array and id corresponding to which the values have changed. Like in the changedDF credit score and credit limit of id=2,name=sunil has been changed.
Hence I wanted the resultant dataframe to give me result like

```
+--+---+------+------+------------+------------+---+
|id   | diffcolumn                        |         
+---+------+------+------------+------------+---
|2   |[, , , credit_score, credit_limit] |
+---+------+------+------------+------------+---+
```

Can anyone suggest me what approach to follow to get eh id and changed column separately in a dataframe.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338412/how-to-compare-two-dataframe-and-print-columns-that-are-different-in-scala

Comment: make use of the aliases : `someDf.select($"a.id",$"diffcolum")` or join on `Seq("id")`

Comment: @RaphaelRoth , your comment helped  me to find the solution Much Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    val aliasedChangedDF = changedDF.as("a")
    val aliasedOriginalDF = originalDF.as("b")
    val diff = udf((col: String, c1: String, c2: String) => if (c1 == c2) "" else col )
    val somedf=aliasedChangedDF.join(aliasedOriginalDF, col("a.id") === col("b.id")).withColumn("diffcolumn", split(concat_ws(",",changedDF.columns.map(x => diff(lit(x), changedDF(x), originalDF(x))):_*),","))
    somedf.select(col("a.id").as("id"),col("diffcolumn"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, these kinds of diffs can easily be done with the [spark-extension](https://github.com/g-research/spark-extension) package.
It provides the `diff` transformation that builds that complex query for you:

```
import uk.co.gresearch.spark.diff._

val options = DiffOptions.default.withChangeColumn("changes")  // needed to get the optional 'changes' column
val diff = originalDF.diff(changedDF, options, "id")

diff.show(false)
+----+----------------------------+---+---------+----------+---------+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|diff|changes                     |id |left_name|right_name|left_city|right_city|left_credit_score|right_credit_score|left_credit_limit|right_credit_limit|
+----+----------------------------+---+---------+----------+---------+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|N   |[]                          |1  |gaurav   |gaurav    |jaipur   |jaipur    |550              |550               |70000            |70000             |
|I   |null                        |4  |null     |Joshua    |null     |cochin    |null             |612               |null             |85000             |
|C   |[credit_score, credit_limit]|2  |sunil    |sunil     |noida    |noida     |600              |650               |80000            |90000             |
|D   |null                        |3  |rishi    |null      |ahmedabad|null      |510              |null              |65000            |null              |
+----+----------------------------+---+---------+----------+---------+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+

diff.select($"id", $"diff", $"changes").show(false)
+---+----+----------------------------+
|id |diff|changes                     |
+---+----+----------------------------+
|1  |N   |[]                          |
|4  |I   |null                        |
|2  |C   |[credit_score, credit_limit]|
|3  |D   |null                        |
+---+----+----------------------------+
```

While this is a simple example, diffing DataFrames can become complicated when wide schemas and null values are involved.
That package is well-tested, so you don't have to worry about getting that query right yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your join condition from `col("a.id") === col("b.id")` to `"id"`

Then, there will be only a single `id` column.

Further, you don't need the `alias("a")` and `alias("b")`. So your join simplifies from

```
changedDF.alias("a").join(originalDF.alias("b"), col("a.id") === col("b.id"))
```

to

```
changedDF.join(originalDF, "id")
```